# How get content between special chars in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm searching for a method in [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails) what give content between special chars.
EX:

> "This is my string, and **<** *this is the content* **>**"
>
> expect result between **<** **>**, "*this is the content*"

Comment: Do you mean all occurrences or just the first one?

Comment: Try this regexp: `"This is my string, and < this is the content > and <another one>".scan(/<(\w|\W)[^>]*>/)` -- see it in action: http://rubular.com/r/bFb8OZoPB9

Comment: this way returns only the firs char btween "< >"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regular expression /<(.*?)>/

```
str = "This is my string, and <test one> < test two >"
str.scan(/<(.*?)>/)
=> [["test one"], [" test two "]]
```

Comment: beat me to it =] what does the i add?

Comment: It makes the pattern case insensitive. In this case, it is unnecessary so I edited and removed the /i flag

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp:

```
"This is my string, and < this is the content > <and more content>. And the tail".scan(/<.*>/)
```

It gives you an array of occurrences:

```
=> ["< this is the content > <and more content>"]
```

Comment: almost this, I need return without the special chars ("< >")

Answer (score 0):

You want a non-greedy capture. This is the regular expression:

```
<(.*?)>
```

See it here: http://rubular.com/r/7KN1HLipyW

ie

```
"This is my string, and < this is the content > and <another one>".scan(/<(.*?)>/)
```